# Proving "$\forall_{\epsilon>0} \exists_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \forall_{n \geq N}: x^{n} < \epsilon$" for $0<x<1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

I'm trying to prove a rather simple analysis statement but I think I'm overseeing something. For $0<x<1$ I need to prove

> $$\forall_{\epsilon>0} \exists_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \forall_{n \geq N}: x^{n} < \epsilon.$$

I now have the following:

We use theorem 1.5 which states

\begin{equation}\label{theorem_1.5}
    \forall_{\epsilon>0}, \exists_{N \in \mathbb{N}} : \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon.
\end{equation}

Also we make use of the fact that if $0<x<1$ it follows that

\begin{equation}\label{equation_1}
    (N+1)x^{N}<\frac{1}{1-x}.
\end{equation}

Suppose $0<x<1$ and let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Now let $\epsilon'=\frac{1}{1-x}\epsilon$. Then from equation 1, equation 2 and the fact that $N+1>N$ it follows that 
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    (N+1)x^{N} &< \frac{1}{1-x},\\
    x^{N} &< \frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{N+1} < \frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{N}\\
    x^{n} &< \frac{1}{1-x} \epsilon\\
    x^{n} &< \epsilon'.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

My gut feeling says there is something wrong with my reasoning. It might be the fact that I predetermine $\epsilon'$, but I'm not sure.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a free variable $x$ in the statement you want to prove. For what values of $x$ do you want to prove it?

Comment: for $0<x<1$, which I also supposed before the last equation.

Comment: You need  to prove $x^n<\epsilon$ but proved $x^n<\epsilon'$ and $\epsilon'$ is greater than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Good point, that is exactly what I do wrong. But any hints in how to overcome it?

Comment: Let $\epsilon'' = (1-x)\epsilon$ and apply "theorem 1.5" for $\epsilon''$ instead of $\epsilon$.

Comment: That's exactly it, precisely the insight I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Put $y=1/x$, then $y>1$, hence $y=1+z$ for some $z>0$. Then we get, with Bernoulli:

$$\frac{1}{x^n}=y^n=(1+z)^n \ge 1+nz >nz.$$

Hence

$$ x^n < \frac{1}{nz}.$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Yes, I can define $\epsilon$ as being $\frac{1}{nz}$. I guess that would work as well.

Comment: No ! Given $ \epsilon >0$, then there is $N$ such that $1/N< \epsilon z.$. For $n>N$ we then have $0<x^n<\frac{1}{nz}< \epsilon $.